# Local push notifications based on condition - Swift

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to set an 'important events' repeated notification where users are notified to check my app based on specific dates that have an important event. So it only sends a notification if there is an important event today.

I have a global variable `isImportant` that is set as true.

Then I have a function with a switch statement that goes through specific dates and returns the important event, and if there are not important events (default), it makes `isImportant = false`

```
var isMainWater = true

func getForMain() -> Waterz {

let database = WaterzBank()

switch getHijriDateNumber() {

case "2-16":
    return database.duaMakarem

case "2-17":
    return database.duaFaraj

case "2-21":
    return database.duaFaraj

default:
    isMainWater = false
    return getWaterzByDayOfWeek(database)

}

}
```

This is how I scheduled my local notification for this:

```
func scheduleImportantNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let item = getWaterForMain()
    content.title = item.entitle ?? "Important Event"
    content.body = "Don't forget to read \(item.entitle ?? "this") today!"

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 18
    dateComponents.minute = 15
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: isMainWater)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: myNotificationID.ImportantNotifiationsID.rawValue, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    notificationCenter.add(request)
}
```

So basically I tried `repeats: isMainWater` so that it would send a notification only if `isMainWater = true`. That didn't work. Even on days with no important event, I would still get a notification and it would be the same important event as the first time. It's not dynamic.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: if you don't want repeated notifications then you should set "repeat" to "false". If you set repeat true then the notification will appear again and again and again

Comment: I want it to repeat when isMainWater = true. How do I do that?

Comment: For your local notification to trigger on different date you have to set dateComponents.day, dateComponents.month or even dateComponents.year in required case.